# OpenNI installation: operation not permitted

Tags: macos, kinect, macos-sierra, simple-openni

I am trying to install kinect on my macOS Sierra (10.12).
I have used the explanation on [greenfoot](http://www.greenfoot.org/doc/kinect/macos.html), so I downloaded Openni, KinectDriver and NITE, extracted them got to the unzipped directory through the terminal and tried to install using the command: `sudo ./install.sh`

This is what I get as a result though:

```
Installing OpenNI
****************************

copying shared libraries...cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.jni.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.dylib: Operation not permitted
```

I have tried to find a solution but i didn't manage to find something that could help me for Sierra.

Comment: have you tried elevating to superuser when installing?

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov I did. I used sudo -s on terminal. Then navigated to the unzipped folder, but i still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rootless issue. Since 10.11, Apple don't give you root power to install the code. Try the second link to see whether you can get the root power back for installation.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/